# Want to add multiple variable's data in one variable, array/list

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to add multiple variables data into one variable so that work can come easy.

```
         string value1 = "bb123";
        string value2 = "bb456";
        string value3 = "bb789";
        string value4 = "bb1011";
        string value5 = "bb736";
        string value6 = "bb66";
        string value7 = "bb67";


        //USERS DATA
        var data  = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value1).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();  
           
        var data2 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value2).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

        var data3 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value3).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

        var data4 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value4).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

        var data5 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value5).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

        var data6 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value6).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

        var data7 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value7).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();          


        //ALL SLOTS
        List<int> AllSlots = db.Slots.Select(x => x.Slot_Id).ToList();
```

I want to store all "data, data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7"...in one variable
so that I can take Except union with "AllData"with AllSlots...

```
    var AllData = ??????.ToList();

var result = AllSlots.Except(data.Union(AllData)).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't tag spam. Just tag what is related to the question. And don't forget to ask a question. Explain the problem you're trying to achieve, describe why what isn't working about your attempt.

Comment: Are the data produced by _db.U...._ the same type for each line? If yes you can merge the result from each call to _db.U..._ in the first list using _data.AddRange(db.U.....ToList())_

Comment: var data  = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == value1).Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

Comment: thats the query which i have used for all above given variable.... only the " == value1" is changed in all the data3,data4,data5,data6,data7 to "==value2","==value3","==value4"....

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: check the post now

Comment: Can i use concat()? but in case of two variable its working perfectly, but if I want to concatinate 7 variables, I can't....

Answer (score 0):

If you query for the same field but with different values then you can just make one single call to your database backend putting all the values to search for in a list and then using this list to filter the field

```
List<string> values = {"123","456","789","1011","736","66","67"};
var data  = db.User_Register_Events
           .Where(x => values.Contains(x.UserTable.User_id)
           .Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();
```

However, I have some doubts about your values. They seems to be integers and not strings. If the field UserTable.User_id is an integer then you should query with an integer list, not strings.

Comment: I have just used static values for now, just to run the query, afterwards the input will be from user side, from interface.... (NOT STATIC)

Comment: Instead of static values, put the variables in the list constructor. _List<string> values = {value1, value2, ....};_